# Can a logic test for an `if` statement be a variable in excel vba?

Tags: excel, variables, if-statement, vba

I have the following function:

```
Function get_equal_array_subset(column_label As String, _
                                                loop_array() As Variant, _
                                                values_array() As Variant)
    ' this function outputs an array of value from the values_array, based on a loop through the loop_array
    ' column_label is the first item in the array of the ouput array; i.e. the column lable of a new range
    ' loop_array is array being looped through and testing each value
    ' valus_array is the array from which values are taken with the test is met in the first array
    ' *** arrays have to be of equal lenght ***


    Dim subset_array() As Variant
    subset_array = Array(column_label)

    Dim rows_dim As Long
    Dim cols_dim As Integer

    Dim agent_subset_counter As Long
    agent_subset_counter = 0 ' counter to set the key for the new array

    For rows_dim = 2 To UBound(loop_array, 1)
        For cols_dim = 1 To UBound(loop_array, 2)

                If loop_array(rows_dim, cols_dim) > 2 Then
                        agent_subset_counter = agent_subset_counter + 1 '  increase the subset counter by 1
                        ReDim Preserve subset_array(agent_subset_counter) ' resize the array account for the next id
                        subset_array(agent_subset_counter) = values_array(rows_dim, cols_dim) ' add the new id to the agent subset
                End If
        Next cols_dim
    Next rows_dim
    get_equal_array_subset = subset_array
End Function
```

Is there a way for me to make the `If loop_array(rows_dim, cols_dim) > 2 Then` a variable?  Let's say I wanted the test to be `> 3` or `= 5` or `non blank`...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the magic `Application.Evaluate()` method of the `Application` class. An example might be to define a series of tests into an array, let's say:

```
Dim myTests(4)
myTests(1) = "> 3"
myTests(2) = "= 5"
myTests(3) = "+3 < 5"
myTests(4) = "- 4 + sum(1,2) < 5"
```

Hence, using the simple statement:

```
If Application.Evaluate(loop_array(rows_dim, cols_dim) & myTests(j)) Then
```

Clearly, the variable `j` should be defined depending on the test you want to use and this kind of method would allow you to define several arrays of operators (one array for operators like `+`, `-` etc., another one for values like `3`, `5` etc.)

**NOTE** If you don't know it yet, the `Application.Evaluate()` method will evaluate the expression and returning the result as Excel would do. It's basically using the same code that Excel uses to evaluate what you write in a cell:

```
Application.Evaluate("2+3") --> 5
Application.Evaluate("2 < 3") --> True
Application.Evaluate("IF(2=3,1,2)") --> 2
'etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to make the "magic number" **2** into a variable, then you would use an array item in place of the **2**.
If, however, you wanted separate logic, then you use use a **Select Case** structure.

Comment: So, select case values can be variables?

Comment: You would create a variable that drives the **Select Case** logic.